# Outlook is not responding due to increased memory

Tags: microsoft-outlook

In my outlook I have mails from past 3 years. Now when I open the microsoft outlook is not responding and always I put it in repair. Now it exceeds the memory. Is archieve the old mail will solve this issue, or is there any other method to solve this issue. Can I move the old mails to my D drive in computer and can access with the same outlook.

Comment: You can create an archive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like the issue is possibly the size of the .pst files (assuming you're using POP accounts).

You should create an archive (which can be set to run automatically and periodically for all accounts). However, this file will also get big!

At one place of work, we would have multiple backup accounts, which we would configure at the start of the year, and it would store 2 years ago. So, as it's 2016 now, the most recent archive would store all of 2014.

In this example, I have 2 archives, one is named archive and the other archive is named NewTest. So, it doesn't matter where the file is stored, providing I have access to it. It also means that, just because it's in an archive doesn't mean I can't access it. Expanding either Archive or NewTest will work in a near identical manner to my main account.

[image]

Comment: Yes I have pop accounts, I s archieve will help in this issue. Whether we can move archieve file to any other location in computer and can see all the old mails in the outlook archieve folder

Comment: The archives will still appear in Outlook!

Comment: So can I move my old emails to archieve and set location in D drive in my computer will solve this issue

Comment: You can try yes. But before you do anything, do take a back up just in case! :)